# how to access/lists in a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I have a tuple where `my_tuple[0]` contains an integer and `my_tuple[1]` contains 3 lists. So

```
my_tuple[0]=11
my_tuple[1]= [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
for tuple_item in my_tuple[1]:
    print tuple_item
```

How could I extract the lists from `my_tuple[1]` without using any external libraries (my current python interpreter has limitations)? I would like to be take the lists from the tuple and then create a dict of lists. Alternatively, I could do a list of lists

```
key=my_tuple[0]
#using the same key 
my_dict[key]= list1
my_dict[key]= list2
my_dict[key]= list3

#or

for tuple_item in my_tuple[1]: 
    list_of_lists.append(tuple_item)
```

Comment: Why do you think you need external libraries?

Comment: By using the same key you would be overriding your previously stored values, since keys are unique in dictionaries.

Comment: ...for that matter, what part of your code (the second form, under the "or" comment) *isn't already working*? Show the actual error you get, not just what you're trying to do.

Comment: What exactly does it mean to "extract" a list?

Comment: If `my_tuple` is a tuple, you shouldn't be able to assign to it either. `tuple`s are immutable. With `my_dict[key]`, you're overwriting each previous value as well because each key is unique.

Comment: by extract, i mean take the lists from the tuple and put them in a new data structure whether that be a list of lists or a dict. my_tuple[0] refers to a triangle so if it was possible I would like to use it as the same key for the triangle vertices (my_tuple[1])

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate a key for each list. In this example, I use the index of each list:

```
my_tuple = [None, None]        # you need a list, otherwise you cannot assign values: mytuple = (None, None) is a tuple
my_tuple[0] = 11
my_tuple[1] = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

dict_of_lists = dict()

for i, tuple_item in enumerate(my_tuple[1]): 
    key = str(i)                      # i = 0, 1, 2; keys should be strings
    dict_of_lists[key] = tuple_item

dict_of_lists

>> {'0': [1, 2, 3], '1': [4, 5, 6], '2': [7, 8, 9]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses. my_tuple[0] corresponds to the number of a triangle and my_tuple[1] corresponds to the vertices so I would like to be able to use them together somehow. When I say extract, I mean I want to take lists out of the tuple and put them in a new type of data structure (dicts, list of lists, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment in response to @Gijs, it sounds like you've got a perfectly good data structure already. Nonetheless, here's another:

```
#python3
from collections import namedtuple
Point = namedtuple("Point", "x, y, z")
Triangle = namedtuple("Triangle", "number, v1, v2, v3")

# Here is your old format:
my_tuple = (11, [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ])

v1 = Point(*my_tuple[1][0])
v2 = Point(*my_tuple[1][1])
v3 = Point(*my_tuple[1][2])
num = my_tuple[0]

new_triangle = Triangle(num, v1, v2, v3)

print(new_triangle)
```

Output is:

```
Triangle(number=11, v1=Point(x=1, y=2, z=3), v2=Point(x=4, y=5, z=6), v3=Point(x=7, y=8, z=9))
```

You can use `new_triangle.num` and `new_triangle.v1` to access members, and you can use `new_triangle.v3.z` to access submembers.

But I'll bet it won't be long before you wish you could loop over the vertices...